# Is it possible to retrieve the headers from an Azure API Gateway call in a Function App?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

Suppose I have a function where I want to print all of the headers passed in to an API Gateway call. Is this possible?

Http Trigger Function App code is below:

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(req.get_json()),
        status_code=200
    )
```

Not seeing any obvious way to retrieve this from the HttpRequest class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.http.httprequest?view=azure-python

Comment: Yeah, they don't make it easy. `method`, `params`, `url`, `route_params` and `headers` are accessible as properties not getter function like `get_body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, just use the "headers" field:

```py
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    for header in req.headers:
        logging.info(f'HEADER KEY {header}')
        logging.info(f'HEADER VALUE {req.headers[header]}')
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "hello",
        status_code=200
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply convert `func.HttpRequest.headers` to a dict:

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    headersAsDict = dict(req.headers)
    logging.info(json.dumps(headersAsDict, indent=2))
    ...
```

Comment: @KHibma Thanks for the edit of the missing parentheses!